# Calendar do datepicker abre e fecha quando clica no botão do submit do formulário

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Olá.

Tô com um problema aqui.

Tenho um formulário em aspnet mvc com c# que tem dois datepicker:

```
<form id="formBuscar" action="PaginaDeDeAcertosDaQuestao" class="form-horizontal box3">

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataDeInicioDaQuestao, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @Value = Model.DataDeInicioDaQuestao, @class = "datepicker", @id = "DataDeInicioDaQuestao"})

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataDeFimDaQuestao, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @Value = Model.DataDeFimDaQuestao, @class = "datepicker", @id = "DataDeInicioDaQuestao"})

</form>
```

Há também o plugin validate do jquery para validar o formulário. Coloquei o método 'validarDiferencaDeDatas' no 'onselect' para validar que a data inicial seja menor que a data final, coloquei validação sobre essas duas datas no plugin validate também. O javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


var validarDiferencaDeDatas = function () {

            $("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao").removeClass("error");
            $("label[for='DataDeInicioDaQuestao']").remove();

            var dataInicio = new Date($("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao").val().split('/')[2], $("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao").val().split('/')[1] - 1, $("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao").val().split('/')[0]);
            var dataFim = new Date($("#DataDeFimDaQuestao").val().split('/')[2], $("#DataDeFimDaQuestao").val().split('/')[1] - 1, $("#DataDeFimDaQuestao").val().split('/')[0])
            var diff = 0;
            if (dataInicio && dataFim) {
                diff = Math.floor((dataFim.getTime() - dataInicio.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day

            }
            if (diff < 0) {
                var validator = $("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao").validate();
                var validador = validator.element("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao").removeClass("error");
                $("label[for='DataDeInicioDaQuestao']").remove();
                return true;
            }
        }

  
   $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            duration: 'fast',
            buttonText: "Calendário",
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showOn: "both",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            buttonImage: "../Content/images/calendario.png",
            clearBtn: true,
            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
            monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
            onSelect: validarDiferencaDeDatas
        });
        
         $.validator.addMethod("validarDatas",
            function (value) {

                $("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao").removeClass("error");
                $("label[for='DataDeInicioDaQuestao']").remove();

                var dataInicio = new Date(value.split('/')[2], value.split('/')[1] - 1, value.split('/')[0]);
                var dataFim = new Date($("#DataDeFimDaQuestao").val().split('/')[2], $("#DataDeFimDaQuestao").val().split('/')[1] - 1, $("#DataDeFimDaQuestao").val().split('/')[0])
                var diff = 0;
                if (dataInicio && dataFim) {
                    diff = Math.floor((dataFim.getTime() - dataInicio.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
                }
                
                if (diff < 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                else {

                    $("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao").removeClass("error");
                    $("label[for='DataDeInicioDaQuestao']").remove();
                    return true;
                }

            }, '@Mensagens.DataFimMaiorQAInicio');

        $("#formBuscar").validate({
           
            rules: {     
                DataDeInicioDaQuestao: {
                    required: true,
                    validarDatas: '#DataDeInicioDaQuestao'
                },
                DataDeFimDaQuestao: {
                    required: true,
                    validarDatas: '#DataDeInicioDaQuestao'
                }
            },
            messages: {
               
                DataDeInicioDaQuestao: {
                    date: '<div class="grid_3"> @Mensagens.Sistema_Campo_Invalido </div>',

                },
                DataDeFimDaQuestao: {
                    date: '<div class="grid_3"> @Mensagens.Sistema_Campo_Invalido </div>',

                }
            }
        });
        
    
    
        $('#btn_submit').click(function (event) {
            $("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao").datepicker("hide");
            if ($('#formBuscar').valid()) {
                $('#PesquisaNova').val(true);
            }
        });
       
  
  });
```

Ele valida perfeitamente. O problema é o seguinte: depois de ter colocado uma data errada e o validate validar da forma correta, qdo eu clico em 'submit' o calendário do datepicker aparece e some rapidamente, mesmo eu colocando o trecho '$("#DataDeInicioDaQuestao").datepicker("hide");' no submit do botão.

Quando eu dou submit com a validação correta (sem erro) isso não acontece.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?